# Gnome DIA change User Interface Language

Tags: open-source, gnome, dia

I am currently using DIA to create Er diagrams. The user interface language is "GERMAN". I would like to change it to "ENGLISH". Does any1 have idea how I could do this?

I did a little bit of research and found that I have to delete the lib/locale folder and DIA will set EN as default lanmguage. I did so but still german is set as a default language.

My operating system : Windows 7 licence version
Language : German

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must change the environment variable LANG and set up to "en_EN". You can do it opening a terminal (executing the command "cmd") and typing:

```
C:\>SET LANG=en_EN
```

And then launching Dia, for example:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Dia\bin\diaw.exe"
```

It works for me in Windows XP.

But you should have made the installation of Dia with all the locales.

Answer (score 5):

or you can make environment variable in advanced system settings in control panel
->
Variable name: LANG
Variable value: en_EN

This you can make to not always typing thats commands in cmd.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the following path:

```
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Dia \ locale
```

Rename the folder for the code language that you do not want the program to be offered by any name you want.
Repeat the process on the following path:

```
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Dia \ lib \ locale
```

Repeat the same process as well as on the following path:

```
C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Dia \ share \ locale
```